# How do I create a new instance containing reference field in Rust?

Tags: rust, dangling-pointer

I'm writing an application that communicates with a database. I thought the `new` method in the `Repository` would initialize the struct member `conn` to the reference of `MysqlConnection::establish(...)` in the below code.

```rust
struct Repository<'a> {
    conn: &'a MysqlConnection,
}

impl<'a> Repository<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            conn: &MysqlConnection::establish(...)
        }
    }

    pub fn new_with_connection(conn: &'a MysqlConnection) -> Self {
        Self {
            conn
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // do something...
}
```

However, I got an error when I try to build the application.

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 | /         Self {
8 | |             conn: &MysqlConnection::establish(...)
  | |                    ------------------------------- temporary value created here
9 | |         }
  | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I've learned from [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#dangling-references) that a function cannot return a dangling reference, but I can't find the way to avoid it in this case. Can I assign a reference to `conn` in the `new` method while keeping `conn` as a reference type?

Comment: As the book you linked to says: *The solution here is to return the `String` directly*. Thus, store the connection directly: `conn: MysqlConnection`. No references.

Comment: See also [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)